# How to retrieve values from object array in jmeter so that i can use the values in HTTP sampler

Tags: jmeter

I'm storing all my `csv` data into an object using `BeanShell PreProcessor`,below is my code

```
 print("Test to store csv values to array");
 String[] str = vars.get("C1").split(",");
 List myList = new ArrayList();
 for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
 {
    myList.add(str[i]);
    print(str[i]);
 }
 vars.putObject("myList", myList);
```

Now i'm able to get all csv data in "myList" object like below

```
myList=[51000011284402, 23456789, 21345, 765432, 6543, 76543]
```

i need to use all these values one after other in my HTTP sampler. I'm using the below code in post body but nothing working

```
<TransactionId>1</TransactionId><CardNumber>${myList[0]}</CardNumber>
```

Help me on how i can use those values in my post body and also is it possible that i can use **str** array in my post body?if yes, then how i can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend doing it a little bit differently, here is a couple of possible options:

1. Reconsider the way you're storing the variables, i.e.

   ```
   for(int i=1;i<=str.length;i++)
   {
       vars.put("myVar_" + i, str[i]);
   }
   ```

   You will get the following variables:

   ```
   myVar_1=51000011284402
   myVar_2=23456789
   etc.
   ```

   You will be able to later iterate the values via [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)
2. Use [bsh.shared](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) namespace and __Beanshell() function combination like:

   - Change the last script line to look like:

     ```
     bsh.shared.myList=myList
     ```
   - In your Request body use __Beanshell() function like:

     ```
     <TransactionId>1</TransactionId><CardNumber>${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.myList.get(0),)}</CardNumber>
     ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter tests

Comment: Solution 1 worked fine for me and it fulfilled my requirement. But, in solution 2 for "bsh.shared.myList=myList" i'm getting empty array like 'host=192.168.152.191
myList= ' Why i'm getting empty array,

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. This was so simple. I was trying to created an array for values retrieved from JSON response but I was not going anywhere instead I used this approach and it solved easily.

Answer (score 1):

This code will be set array values as a merged string to variable.

```
var myNewArray = vars.get("arrayname");
// myNewArray ==> "123,124,125,126"
```

Arrays use comma to split values. You can use split function to get string as a array.

```
var myNewArray = vars.get("arrayname").split(",");
// myNewArray ==> [ 123, 124, 125, 126 ]
```